# Find source of zombie threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdb, pthreads

I have an application which I'm pretty sure 'leaks' threads by forgetting to call pthread_join on them. So their stacks are not cleared up and the process over time consumes huge amounts of virtual address space.

Is there a way to find a place in the software which creates those threads or at least find out what those threads were doing before exiting?

My application is big and creates a lot of thread which are correctly joined. So catching all pthread operations is impractical. I need something more precise.

I was able to come up with an isolated reproducer of what I think is happening.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker (void* unusued)
{
    // Do nothing
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;

    for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
            pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &worker, NULL);
    }
    sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

After running it, 'top' shows that 16GB of virtual address space is consumed

[image]

But 'ps' and 'gdb' show only one thread

[image]

[image]

I have sources for everything in my application. So I can add any code or other instrumentation needed.

In other words, how having a running instance of the above application find out that it has 2000 'lost' threads and how to find out that they executed worker() function?

Comment: As far as I know, a pthread terminates when the function returns, or the thread can call pthread_exit(). If your worker isn't doing anything, it's pretty normal that you have only the main thread remaining.

Comment: You created 2000 threads, each of which with a default stack (which is probably 2 MB). That would have called for a lot of virtual memory, almost none of which was ever actually used or assigned real memory. Run `htop`, and display as tree. It will show you all of the processes and their threads.

Comment: @Christophe pthread terminates but never cleans up its stack and other thread related data. See 'top' output above.

Comment: @user4581301 on 64bit Ubuntu each thread consumes 16MB and over weeks it accumulates in a lot of gigabytes of the virtual address space. At some point Linux rejects creating new threads and the application becomes unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. One possible answer is to use `libpthread` interposer. See [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926).

Let's make your test program a bit more interesting, so it "leaks" only a few threads, and joins most of them:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker(void* unusued)
{
  // Do nothing
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread_id;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &worker, (void*)i);
    if (i != 4 && i != 7) pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
  }
  sleep(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Now let's build an interposer for `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <map>

static pthread_mutex_t mtx;
typedef std::pair<void *, void *> elem_t;
typedef std::map<pthread_t, elem_t> map_t;
static map_t thr_map;

extern "C"
int pthread_create(pthread_t *tid, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg)
{
  static __decltype(pthread_create) *real
    = reinterpret_cast<__decltype(pthread_create) *>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,
                                                           "pthread_create"));
  int rc = (*real)(tid, attr, start_routine, arg);
  if (rc == 0) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    thr_map[*tid] = std::make_pair((void*)start_routine, arg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  }
  return rc;
}

extern "C"
int pthread_join(pthread_t tid, void **arg)
{
  static __decltype(pthread_join) *real
    = reinterpret_cast<__decltype(pthread_join) *>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,
                                                         "pthread_join"));
  int rc = (*real)(tid, arg);
  if (rc == 0) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    const auto it = thr_map.find(tid);
    assert(it != thr_map.end());
    thr_map.erase(it);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

Build it: `g++ -g -fPIC -shared -o thr.so thr.cc -ldl -std=c++11` and use it:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./thr.so ./a.out &
[1] 37057

gdb -q -p 37057

Attaching to process 37057
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f95831a2f3d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.

(gdb) set print pretty
(gdb) p thr_map
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  [140280106567424] = {
    first = 0x40069d <worker(void*)>,
    second = 0x7
  },
  [140280114960128] = {
    first = 0x40069d <worker(void*)>,
    second = 0x4
  }
}
```

Voilà: you now know which threads have not been joined, which routine(s) they were invoked with, and what argument was given to them.

**EDIT**

> My application is linked statically

In that case, linker `--wrap=pthread_create` and `--wrap=pthread_join` are your friends. Documentation [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html).

Comment: It looks promising. My application is fully statically linked but I think I could rebuild it with dynamic linking or figure out how to run this statically. In any case thank you.